# DefaultRoute throws "Cannot call a class as a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm using react-router with ES6 classes and it keeps throwing the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

It refers to the declaration of the default route. Most of the code is taken from the example in the react-router repo, which is why I'm wondering why it's buggy.

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';

import {Header} from './components/Header.react.jsx';

var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var App = React.createFactory(React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }
}));


var Inbox = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        test
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Inbox}/> // ERROR
  </Route>
);


Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Comment: Either you're transforming it with an old transpiler version, or using an old version of react-router.

Comment: I switched from tranceur to babelify and updated react-router and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you wrapping `App` component creation with `createFactory` call?

The following works just fine with me (I just removed `Header` since it is external):

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';


var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var Inbox = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        test2
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Inbox}/> // ERROR
  </Route>
);


Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Comment: What transpiler did you use?